# How to handle a windows prompt in a test automation using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, prompt

I am new to using Cypress for web automation. I am still scouring through the internet looking for answers to this but I cannot find a solution that works for me.
This is what I'm trying to do in my test:

- User clicks a link.
- A new tab is opened and a windows prompt appears, requesting user input (username, password). 
  *(Since Cypress doesn't allow opening new tabs, I've removed the `target` attribute.)*
- Upon logging in successfully, the page has a download button.
- User clicks on the download button.

---

**The first struggle** - I could not enter values into the windows prompt. In the below code, I was trying to see if the 'Sign In' button on the windows prompt would be clicked, but it was not.

```
cy.window().then(win => {
    cy.get('@documentPassword').then((finalPassword) => {
        const stub =cy.stub(win, 'prompt')
        stub.returns('test')
        cy.get('button#signin').click()
    })
})
```

I got an Assertion Error: `Timed out retrying after 25000ms: Expected to find element: button#signin, but never found it.`

After no luck with this, I moved on to another suggestion.

---

**The second struggle** - I tried putting the username and password into the link, like this: `https://username:password@mytestingwebsite.com`. Just to note, when I paste the link manually into a browser, it works. To test this out, this what I had done:

```
cy.visit('https://mailtrap.io')
// ...other steps
cy.forceVisit('https://username:password@mytestingwebsite.com')
```

I added a custom command `forceVisit` to the `commands.js` file:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('forceVisit', url => {
    cy.window().then(win => {
        return win.open(url, '_self'); 
      });
});
```

The [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNBdJ.png) is the second url does not load. 
Hoping for any insight from you guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at window.onbeforeload blog post? It might help you out.
https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/onbeforeunload/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
cy.visit('https://mytestingwebsite.com', {
  auth: {
   username: 'username',
   password: 'password'
  }
})
```

This didn't work for me the first time I tried it because I still passed the credentials in the url.